# Change permission of an image after uploading it within a lambda function in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible? After I'm uploading the image it has no permissions. I thought it should work with putting `ACL: 'public-read'` in data. 
This is my code:

```
var data = {ACL: 'public-read', Bucket: 's3.bucket', Key: 'latest.png', Body: result.Body, ContentLength: result.ContentLength};

s3.putObject(data, function(err, output_data) {
   if (err) {
              console.log('Error uploading data: ', err); 
            }
            else {
             console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
            }
  });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error uploading data:  { AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:539:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'Access Denied',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2017-05-17T11:16:29.747Z,
```

The bucket itself has all permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Your error shows region: null. 
S3 have unique global endpoint but it saves your data at some specific location and you have to provide region while uploading content to s3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem. Didn't  know that I have to put "s3:PutObjectAcl" into the Policy.